How to correctly serialize objects in Cyrillic using JaxbContent and specify encoding in the Windows-1251 declaration?
I have a Java method that serializes objects to xml, but it fails with an error:
    public <T extends XmlSerializable> String serializeAndValidateXml(String xmlName, T xmlSerializable, String prefix) throws MinioException, SaxonApiException, SAXException, JAXBException {
        String s;
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(xmlSerializable.getClass());
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "windows-1251");

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(byteArrayOutputStream, "windows-1251");
            marshaller.marshal(xmlSerializable, outputStreamWriter);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();

            s = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("windows-1251");

            log.info("Generated XML:\n{}", s);

            XsdSchema xsdSchema = xsdSchemaRepository.findByPrefixAndEndDateIsNullOrderBySchemaVersionDesc(prefix).stream()
                    .filter(xsd -> xsd.getExtension().equals(XSD_TYPE.toLowerCase()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Не найдена XSD схема для префикса: " + prefix));

            String xsdSchemaName = xsdSchema.getName();

            InputStream xsdInputStream;
            try {
                xsdInputStream = minioService.getSchema(xsdSchemaName, XSD_TYPE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new MinioException("Ошибка загрузки XSD схемы из Minio: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            List<String> validationErrors = xmlValidator.validateXML(xsdInputStream, s, xsdSchemaName, xmlName);

            if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
                String errorMessage = formatValidationErrors(validationErrors);
                throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage);
            }

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка сериализации XML с использованием JAXB", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка ввода-вывода при сериализации XML", e);
        }
        log.debug("XML = {}", s);

        return s;
    }

Here is the XML that is generated:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" standalone="yes"?>
<Файл ИдФайл="ON_RISKNALMON_7700_7700_7710016640770701001_20241031_c76274c6-ca5b-45f7-87d8-0e325c445615" ВерсПрог="Налогоплательщик ЮЛ" ВерсФорм="5.02">
    <Документ КНД="1125308" ДатаДок="31.10.2024" КодНО="7700" ГодНМ="2024" Период="31" НомерРед="1">
        <СвНП>
            <НПЮЛ НаимОрг="Публичное акционерное общество &quot;Московская городская телефонная сеть&quot;" ИННЮЛ="7710016640" КПП="770701001"/>
        </СвНП>
        <Подписант ПрПодп="2" Долж="Директор департамента">
            <ФИО Фамилия="Корнев" Имя="Дмитрий" Отчество="Александрович"/>
            <СвПред НаимДок="Доверенность б/н от 01.04.2021"/>
        </Подписант>
        <РискОргНМ ОКВЭД="61.10" ОблРиск="01.1" КодРиск="RISK001" НаимРиск="Неплатежные обязательства" ОписРиск="Невыполнение обязательств по кредитным договорам" НапрРиск="2201" КатегорРиск="1" КодНалог="012101" Статья="151" Пункт="1" Подпункт="-" Абзац="-" ВероятРиск="01" ПоследРиск="500000" УровРискОрг="1"/>
        <РискОргНМ ОКВЭД="61.20" ОблРиск="01.2" КодРиск="RISK002" НаимРиск="Ущерб окружающей среде" ОписРиск="Загрязнение водных ресурсов в результате несанкционированной сброса отходов" НапрРиск="2105" КатегорРиск="2" КодНалог="012102" Статья="215" Пункт="2" Подпункт="-" Абзац="-" ВероятРиск="02" ПоследРиск="2000000" УровРискОрг="2"/>
        <РискОргНМ ОКВЭД="61.10" ОблРиск="02.1" КодРиск="RISK003" НаимРиск="Кредитный риск" ОписРиск="Невозможность погашения займов в срок" НапрРиск="2202" КатегорРиск="1" КодНалог="012103" Статья="160" Пункт="1" Подпункт="-" Абзац="-" ВероятРиск="03" ПоследРиск="1000000" УровРискОрг="3"/>
        <РискОргНМ ОКВЭД="61.20" ОблРиск="02.2" КодРиск="RISK004" НаимРиск="Риск утраты клиентов" ОписРиск="Потеря клиентов в результате некачественного обслуживания" НапрРиск="2203" КатегорРиск="2" КодНалог="012104" Статья="151" Пункт="2" Подпункт="-" Абзац="-" ВероятРиск="04" ПоследРиск="800000" УровРискОрг="2"/>
        <РискОргНМ ОКВЭД="61.20" ОблРиск="06.1" КодРиск="RISK008" НаимРиск="Риск утраты репутации" ОписРиск="Ухудшение репутации компании в результате скандала" НапрРиск="2204" КатегорРиск="2" КодНалог="012204" Статья="151" Пункт="3" Подпункт="-" Абзац="-" ВероятРиск="03" ПоследРиск="1000000" УровРискОрг="3"/>
        <РискОргНМ ОКВЭД="61.20" ОблРиск="08.1" КодРиск="RISK010" НаимРиск="Риск экологических аудитов" ОписРиск="Несоответствие экологическим нормам и стандартам" НапрРиск="2205" КатегорРиск="2" КодНалог="012301" Статья="215" Пункт="4" Подпункт="-" Абзац="-" ВероятРиск="05" ПоследРиск="1800000" УровРискОрг="2"/>
    </Документ>
</Файл>

In the end I get this error:
Error on line 2 column 3    SXXP0003   Error reported by XML parser: Element type "Р[x420]" must be followed by either   attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". Error    SXXP0003  SXXP0003   Error reported by XML parser: Element type "Р[x420]" must be followed by   either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I asked GPT what the problem is, it says that the parser can't recognize Cyrillic characters, but I can't not use them, that's the point of the task.
I also tried using XMLMapper, but as I understand it, it doesn't provide tools that would help me set the correct declaration in XML.
DOM doesn't suit me, because I'm developing an automated API that generates XML on its own. Unfortunately, UTF-8 encoding also doesn't suit me, although everything works with it.
If it is necessary, then I use Java 17

So far I have found only this way, after serialization use this method:
private String changeXmlDeclaration(String xml) {
return xml.replace("", "");
}
But I am not satisfied with this approach

You don't show what the xmlValidator is. It really looks like the validator cannot handle the "windows-1251" code page, or that it is misconfigured.
